# Handling unknown shipping costs via PayPal Express nvp API

Tags: paypal

Can some confirm something for me; I've searched PayPal's docs and just can't find the answer.

If calling SetExpressCheckout with the parameter 'TOTALTYPE'= 'EstimatedTotal', how much headroom does PayPal allow for finalizing the transaction?

For example, someone carts an item that has a cost of $1.  They click PayPal Express and get sent to PayPal to authorize an estimated amount of $1.  Then they return to the merchant site and now that their address is known, the cart says shipping is +$20.

Is that acceptable?  I'd really like to understand the groundrules on this, as I don't want to risk any authorization errors due to insufficient order amount when making the request.

Comment: Yes it is acceptable there is no way of determining the shipping cost of the customer before hand with no input. You can have the customer submit some data before hand if you want to get a better estimate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have to answer my own question here.  I called PayPal.  The answer is "it's handled, don't worry about it".  They would rather not publish the details on their proprietary algorithm because there are fraud tests, etc. going on -- but said it is a key design point for them and it is absolutely handled no worries.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not passing a SHIPPINGAMT variable with the SetExpressCheckout call, then we will not display or "calculate" shipping on the PayPal page.  When they are transferred to the PayPal page the customer is not authorizing the payment per se, rather they are selecting their payment method/funding source to be used when the DoExpressCheckout call is passed.

Only after the customer is transferred back to your page, and the final order total is known and passed via the DoExpressCheckout is the payment initiated. The difference between the total amount in the Set call and the Do call does not matter.  Perhaps the agent with whom you were speaking with under the impression of an authorize/capture structure being in place. This will limit the final capture amount to the authorized amount +/- 20%.

Of course this is all turned on its head if you are passing the USERACTION=COMMIT variable which will "finalize" the payment on the PayPal page, while the DoExpress call is run transparently on your end. This will change the text on the button on the PayPal page to "Pay Now" instead of "Continue: You're almost done. You will confirm your payment on yourwebsitehere.com"

I hope this helps!